# What is the difference between dictionaries created from vars() and dict={}?

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

After reading about vars(), I am still a little confused on what it is actually doing. In looking at the Python documentation, "The vars() function returns the __ dict __ attribute of the given object if the object has __ dict __ attribute." So, it returns a dictionary object? Here are the questions I am really getting at:

1) What is vars() actually doing in the below code?

```
dict = {}
dict['H'] = atom
vars()[dict['H']] = 20
```

2) Why is the vars() necessary in front of the dictionary I created and could I leave it out? (I know the code fails if I leave it out, but what would be a different way of accomplishing the same task?)

```
dict = {}
dict['H'] = atom
dict['H'] = 20
```

Comment: 1) Keep reading: "Without an argument, vars() acts like locals(). **updates to the locals dictionary are ignored**." 2) Can you explain what you mean by "fails"?

Comment: You are missing a key piece of data... what's in `atom`?

Comment: By "fails" I was getting syntax errors. This was because I left the brackets around dict['H'] after getting rid of the vars().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) What is `vars()` doing in the below code

Honestly, it's hard to tell.  `vars()` (without an argument) returns the local namespace as a dictionary.  In other words, it does the same thing as [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals).  In your code, you then look up a name (`dict['H']`) in the locals dict and set an item in there.  Setting an item in the dict returned by `locals()` does nothing if you are in a function... If you are in the global namespace, it adds an attribute.

> 2) Why is the `vars()` necessary in front of the dictionary I created and could I leave it out?

It probably isn't necessary and you probably *should* leave it out.  Normally *dynamically* setting attributes on the global namespace is a really bad idea.  You should generally pass around a dictionary of the data that you need instead.  In other words, you *can* do:

```
v = 'foo'
globals()[v] = 'bar'
# ...
value = globals()[v]  # 'bar'
```

But you *shouldn't*.  It's much better to just pass a dictionary around:

```
v = 'foo'
dct = {v: 'bar'}
# ...
value = dct[v]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just went through the entire code and got rid of the vars() and everything is "nice" now.

Answer (score 3):

> What is vars() actually doing in the below code?

It does what it always does: it retrieves all local variables as a dictionary. That's how it works when calling `vars` *without* arguments.

> Why is the vars() necessary in front of the dictionary I created and could I leave it out?

It seems that someone is doing shenanigans with the local scope. It's just that it is wrapped with `dict['H']` which is just some variable (possibly `atom` is a string). In other words he's trying to retrieve a variable by dynamic name. For example

```
>>> test = 15
>>> x = 'test'
>>> vars()[x]
15
```

This should be **avoided** at all costs. Forget you even know about the existance of `vars()`. I do not know a single case when you have to use `vars()` instead of a dict or some other "normal" (and in this context safe) structure. The code you are looking at is insanely difficult to maintain, error prone and has serious security issues.

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't overwrite `__builtin__` functions. `dict` is a reserved name for a function used to create dictionary objects.

Second, `var` gives you access to name declarations within the current running scope.